# Unstable values in ArUco pose estimation

Tags: c++, opencv, aruco

I'm trying to find the orientation of the camera using Aruco marker. Euler angles extracted from the rotation matrix are unstable beyond a certain point.
As the distance of the camera increases from the marker, the yaw angle values of camera is just unstable. The "Z" axis on the marker flips.
The euler angles are jittery, not the same in every frame and take time to stabilize. How do I obtain some reliable values of the yaw angle and distance between the camera and marker?
I am trying to find the pose of moving camera w.r.t a static marker.
I implemented **solvePnP** and **solvePnPRansac** both yielding in unstable results.
The rotation matrix obtained  after converting rotation vectors from **estimatePoseSingleMarker**  seems alright up to a certain point but loses stability.
How do I go about this?
Thank you

Answer (score 10):

In general, you won't get accurate camera pose estimation from a single marker. The solution is to add more markers. You could use either a marker board, or a more sparse pattern of markers.

As a single marker gets further from the camera, several factors work to reduce the accuracy of the marker pose estimate.

1. the projected size of the marker becomes smaller and more quantized by the pixel grid. Distance is estimated by inverse perspective division, so it becomes less accurate as distance increases.
2. perspective distortion reduces, approaching a parallel projection. In a parallel projection the marker has two equally viable orientations, which may be returned alternately (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necker_cube). The orientation of the marker relative to the camera is also significant - in more perpendicular views of the marker (orthographic projection), pitch and yaw of the marker are ambiguous, compared to oblique views. Reduced perspective distortion with distance makes this effect worse, and will cause the calculated camera pose to yaw, pitch, and move laterally.
3. given the smaller number of pixels in the marker, small scale effects such as sensor noise and quantization become more significant, reducing stability from frame to frame and causing jitter.

As you have discovered, pose estimation works OK in close-up, oblique views of a single marker, because the projected points given to solvePnP() are far apart and have large perspective distortion. By adding more markers, you always have ideal projected points for solvePnP().

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed informative. Can I implement some sort of filtering technique to stabilize the values?

Comment: I added another marker and is adjacent to the first one. I get two sets of results which are not the same. There's some slight difference between the two sets values. Since there are 2 sets of values one for each marker, I am confused as what values to consider.

Comment: You need to know where the corners of all your markers are, with respect to some 3D coordinate system, so measure this first. Detect as many markers as you can, build the list of 3D corner coordinates and corresponding projected 2D coordinates, and pass to solvePnP().  This will give you a best fit solution for your camera pose across all the corner points of all the visible markers.  It will be much more stable than solving each marker individually using estimatePoseSingleMarker(), which has all the problems described above.

Comment: The simplest solution is to use an ArUco board, which does all the steps I describe for you.  Note that "boards" don't need to be a regular grid of markers, nor even planar.  I've defined a "board" for a cube covered with markers and it worked just fine.  Just make sure your "board" matches your real arrangement of markers as closely as you can.

Comment: Hey can you provide any leads to research papers which describe the effects you mentioned in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Since the other angles are dependent in the algorithm, make sure to check the roll value if its changing accordingly. Which would be most responsible for the z-flip, so just make basic filter to avoid that noise.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).