# Improve accuracy of pose with bigger ArUco markers

Tags: c++, opencv, aruco

Referring to the original [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709522/unstable-values-in-aruco-pose-estimation), would the pose accuracy of camera improve when a relatively larger marker of length say 0.65m is used?

Comment: For better accuracy, there are more than one parameters. Your camera should be calibrated well, your resolution can be higher to get more sampling and better estimation, your marker can be enclosed or you can use marker maps and so on. Of course with larger marker you may get better accuracy(don't think the other parameters) but it my effect bad if you will be near to the marker. For example, you can't see the whole marker 1 meter away if your field of view is narrow. I suggest to read the documentation, there are tips for better estimation.

Comment: I already calibrated my camera. Do you think re-calibrating the camera would improve the results? My concern is the pose values are good at closer distances but unstable at larger distances. So I thought increasing the size of the marker might help at larger distances.

Comment: Re-calibration may go well or not. It depends the quality and variety of the images. You can check reprojection error to see if the calibration is okay or not. Just an example, my reprojection error is 2.4 and 2.2 for my stereo cameras.
If your camera calibration is suffiecient for you, I suggest check your camera resolution. You can sacrifice your FPS to get better resolution (if camera supports it, check from hardware options or google it) as you say you can try fro bigger markers and enclosed markers. Many ways to do it. And you can give your results here for better understanding.

Comment: what do you mean by "enclosed marker"?

Comment: For corner subpixel accuracy, You are adding extra 4 squares near to corners. This is harder to detect but pose estimation accuracy is better most of the time( ignoring other params like calibration quality). You can see from documentation as I said before:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QU9KoBtjSM2kF6ITOjQ76xqL7H0TEtXriJX5kwi9Kgc/edit#

Answer (score 3):

Using a single marker will have all the problems described in the original question, regardless of the size of the marker. If you scale up your marker size by some scale factor F, all that happens is that the minimum and maximum distances at which you can reliably use the marker also scale up by factor F. The gain in maximum distance is offset by the corresponding loss of minimum distance. It doesn't really change the problem fundamentally.

The key to reliable pose estimation is to arrange your markers so that, regardless of where the camera is, there are decodable markers whose corners cover a large part of your viewport. Roughly speaking, your minimum distance occurs when individual markers become too large to fit in the viewport, and your maximum distance occurs when individual markers become too small for your camera to resolve and decode. The range of distances you can use thus depends on your camera resolution and quality. If you need even more range, you can use several different marker sizes at once, eg. nested markers.